# colorbar with definite number of discrete colours; with matching ticks placement

Tags: pgfplots

Why is it so difficult in Pgfplots to configure a colourbar with a user-defined number of discrete colours and with ticks exactly placed on the borders between the colours?

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  domain=-2:2,
  view={0}{90},
  colormap={CM}{
  samples of colormap=(13 of hot)},
  colormap access=piecewise constant,
  colorbar right,
  colorbar style={%
     ymin=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min},
     ytick distance={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta max}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min})/13.0},
%     ytick={%
%       \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min},%
%       \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min}+(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta max}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min})/13.0}%
%       \pgfmathresult,%
%       ...,%
%       \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta max}
%     }
  }  
]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp]
{exp(-x^2-y^2)*x+0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which, unfortunately, produces only:

[image]

How do I force Pgfplots to place ticks at the colourbar ends at `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min}` and `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta max}`, and to evenly distribute the remaining ticks to fall exactly on the colour transitions?

My next attempt (see out-commented section in the code) making use of `ytick={<first>,<second>,...,<last>}` option and by means of `\pgfmathparse{...}` to compute the `<second>` tick, ended up in a TeX parsing error.

What else can I do to get the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ytick=data`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  domain=-2:2,
  view={0}{90},
  colormap={CM}{
  samples of colormap=(13 of hot)},
  colormap access=piecewise constant,
  colorbar right,
  colorbar style={%
     ytick=data,
  }  
]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp]
{exp(-x^2-y^2)*x+0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This requires pgfplots 1.14 (the most recent stable).

[image]

Note that the image is 1:1 equivalent to

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  domain=-2:2,
  view={0}{90},
  colorbar right,
  colorbar style={%
     ytick=data,
  }  
]
\addplot3[contour filled={number=13}]
{exp(-x^2-y^2)*x+0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

except that `contour filled` allows somewhat more freedom to choose the contour positions.

Comment: These are great additions to `pgfplots`,  thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Explicit setting of the colour bar ticks using

```
colorbar style={
  ytick={<first>,<first>+(<last>-<first>)/<levels>,...,<last>}
}
```

does the trick.

The three ticklist elements `<first>,<second>,...,<last>` must be calulated based on the values of `/pgfplots/point meta min` and `/pgfplots/point meta max` and the desired number of colour `<levels>` .

However, the PGF-provided math parsing facilities `\pgfmathparse{...}` and `\pgfmathresult` seem to be unusable for the evaluation of floating point expressions in the axis configuration. Nor may `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min}` and `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta max}` be directly used inside `ytick={...}` to set the limits.

Most fortunately, there is the LaTeX3 expandable math parser `\fp_eval:n{...}` which graciously accomplishes the tick calculation and which is also used to wrap the lower and upper tick limits.

***UPDATE***

As of PGFPlots-**1.14**, `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta max}` returns values with leading and trailing characters which do not belong to the fp numbers and cause `\fp_eval:n` to fail inside ytick={...}. As a workaround the calculations are moved into `every tick/.append code={...}`.

Example with 13 colour levels:

[image]

Code for current PGFPlots-**1.14**:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \fpEval{<expression>}
% expandably evaluate floating point <expression>
\let\fpEval\fp_eval:n
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  domain=-2:2,
  view={0}{90},
  colormap={CM}{
  samples of colormap=(13 of hot)},
  colormap access=piecewise constant,
  colorbar right,
  colorbar style={%
     ytick={%
       \aval,\bval,...,\cval%
%       \fpEval{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min}},%
%       \fpEval{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min}+(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta max}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min})/13},
%       ...,
%       \fpEval{2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta max}}
     },
     every tick/.append code={%
       \xdef\aval{\fpEval{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min}}}
       \xdef\bval{\fpEval{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min}+(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta max}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min})/13}}
       \xdef\cval{\fpEval{2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta max}}}
     }
  },
]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp]
{exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Code for previous PGFPlots-1.13:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \fpEval{<expression>}
% expandably evaluate floating point <expression>
\let\fpEval\fp_eval:n
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  domain=-2:2,
  view={0}{90},
  colormap={CM}{
  samples of colormap=(13 of hot)},
  colormap access=piecewise constant,
  colorbar right,
  colorbar style={%
     ytick={%
       \fpEval{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min}},%
       \fpEval{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min}+(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta max}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta min})/13},%
       ...,%
       \fpEval{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/point meta max}*2} %increase limit to ensure placement of uppermost tick label
     }
  }
]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp]
{exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `pgfplots` falls back to TikZ' `\foreach` macro for the key evaluations (not computations),  and that doesn't evaluate the expressions and pretty limited to TeX arithmetic.

Comment: @percusse No problem, as the expandable alternative `\fp_eval:n{}` exists.